# GStreamer: Pipeline to write data to file based on condition

Tags: c, video, video-streaming, gstreamer

**Is there a way to write data in a *GStreamer* pipeline to a file based on an (external) condition?**

I have an application/code, which streams/displays video to the screen and continuously writes it to a file (it works fine).
I would like to have the *GStreamer pipeline* to only write to a file if an external condition is *true* (at runtime - I don't know the condition in advance).

**What I have done so far:**
I carefully searched the official *GStreamer* documentation, where I found some information on `appsink`, but I don't really see a way how to apply it based on an (external) conditional.

I also used *'dynamic pipelines'* as a search term, which seems describe the modification of *GStreamer pipelines* based on conditions.

I also searched the GStreamer mailing list and found [this](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Conditional-linking-of-audiosink-element-in-pipeline-td1567403.html) post, which uses the `gst_element_set_locked_state()` function.
I added a

```
if (condition) {
    gst_element_set_locked_state(videosink, 'TRUE');
} else {
    gst_element_set_locked_state(videosink, 'FALSE');
}
```

to my code by then the pipeline would not work at all (displaying a black image).

**Another way** is described on https://coaxion.net/blog/2014/01/gstreamer-dynamic-pipelines/ in **Example 2** with the corresponding code being available on GitHub (https://github.com/sdroege/gst-snippets/blob/217ae015aaddfe3f7aa66ffc936ce93401fca04e/dynamic-tee-vsink.c).
It seems to use a callback and the `gst_element_set_state (sink->sink, GST_STATE_NULL)` function call to write to a file based on an (external) condition.

Applying this function in analogy to the function above causes the pipeline to display find, but also results in continuous (and not conditional) output to a file:

```
if (condition) {
    gst_element_set_state(videosink, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
} else {
    gst_element_set_state(videosink, GST_STATE_NULL);
}
```

Also `gst_pad_add_probe ()` could be a possibility to dynamically change output to a file, but despite having loocked in the *GStreamer* documentation, I don't know how use this function correctly.

Answer (score 1):

For your requirement you need ***tee*** and ***valve*** elements.
Tee will seperate the pipeline for both displaying to window and writing to a file. Valve is the condition you are looking. Its drop attribute drops the frame where the valve is.

Your pipeline will be like:

```
gst-launch-1.0 ksvideosrc ! videoconvert ! tee name=t ! queue ! valve drop=false ! autovideosink t. ! queue ! valve drop=false ! openh264enc ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location="test.mp4" -v --eos-on-shutdown
```

When your condition occurres, set your specific valve's drop attribute as true for not continuing to write file.

In C/C++:

```
if(condition)
   g_object_set(videoValve,"drop",true,nullptr);
else
   g_object_set(videoValve,"drop",false,nullptr);
```

**WARNING:**
Valve elements must be false until data will pass inside everything in the pipeline. Which means, you can set valve's drop attribute as true when the pipeline is on PLAYING State. You can adjust your code accordingly such as trigger the mechanism on BusCallback, you can reach pipeline states inside that.

Note: ksvideosrc (Windows) if you use Unix try v4lsrc.

If you build your application like this, it will work, I use similar scenario.

Comment: With help of <http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/Using-the-valve-plugin-correctly-in-a-gstreamer-pipeline-td4682904.html>, I realized that it becomse necessary to manually control the state of the `filesink` element behind the `valve`. But after doing so with the function `gst_element_set_state()`, I finally managed to run the code.